# Lithium Views in Sub-directories

Tags: php, lithium

I am working on a website using the Lithium framework for PHP, and I need to have two sub-directories (ie. for admin and blog) with my controllers and views:

```
-controllers
  -admin
    HomeController.php
    ...
  -blog
    HomeController.php
    ...
  HomeController.php
  ...

-views
  -admin
    -home
      index.html.php
      ...
    ...
  -blog
    -home
      index.html.php
      ...
    ...
  -layouts
    default.html.php
    admin.html.php
    blog.html.php
```

So far, I have discovered the way to allow the use of sub-domains in the controller using the `Dispach::config()` method:

```
Dispatcher::config(array('rules' => array(
  'admin' => array('controller' => 'app\controllers\admin\{:controller}Controller'),
  'blog' => array('controller' => 'app\controllers\blog\{:controller}Controller'),
)));
```

This works when you use the following routing:

```
$options = array('continue' => true);

Router::connect('/admin', array(
  'admin' => true,
  'controller' => 'Home'
), $options);

Router::connect('/admin/{:args}', array(
  'admin' => true
), $options);

Router::connect('/blog', array(
  'blog' => true,
  'controller' => 'Home'
), $options);

Router::connect('/blog/{:args}', array(
  'blog' => true
), $options);
```

Now the problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to set it to automatically use the `admin/blog` template and `admin/blog` view folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override default templates paths thanks to Media.
The filter above sets different paths for admin requests (in config/bootstrap/media.php).

```
Dispatcher::applyFilter('_callable', function($self, $params, $chain) {
  $next = $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);

  if ($params['request']->admin) {

    Media::type('default', null, array(
        'view' => 'lithium\template\View',
        'paths' => array(
            'layout' => '{:library}/views/layouts/{:layout}.{:type}.php',
            'template' => '{:library}/views/admin/{:controller}/{:template}.{:type}.php'
        )
    ));
  }

return $next;

});
```

Comment: and this should help you too: http://mariuskubilius.tumblr.com/post/35792864632/lithium-media-render-filter-to-serve-layouts